# Issue with plugin: Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with JIRA SAML SSO by Microsoft

Tags: azure, plugins, single-sign-on, jira

I'm having multiple issues with the Jira plugin: "Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with JIRA SAML SSO by Microsoft".

Issues:

- The plugin gets installed with an error message: "An unexpected error
  occurred. Refer to the logs for more information."
- Jira's catalina.out contains errors, please see log output below
- Plugin's configuration cannot be saved - the Save button is "grayed out". [Image of the grayed out Save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3RLd.jpg)

Tech info:

- Jira On-Prem version 8.13
- Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
- OS: CentOS 7.7
- Plugin version: 1.0.12

URL to the plugin's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/jiramicrosoft-tutorial

Log output

```
AI: INFO 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
AI: INFO 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: 'MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity': null value is replaced with '500'
AI: INFO 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: 'FlushIntervalInSeconds': null value is replaced with '5'
AI: TRACE 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Using Http Client version 4.3+
AI: TRACE 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: No back-off container defined, using the default 'EXPONENTIAL'
AI: INFO 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: 'Channel.MaxTransmissionStorageCapacityInMB': null value is replaced with '10'
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.MyContextInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.MyContextInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to scan packages 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights': exception: 'org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersBundleURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection'
AI: TRACE 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Default performance counters will be automatically loaded.
AI: TRACE 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Windows performance counters are not relevant on this OS.
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule not found by com.microsoft.MSSsoJiraPlugin [191]
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Failed to create performance module: 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule'
AI: ERROR 26-11-2020 20:54, 37: Error while creating performance counters: 'com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean'
```

Answer (score 0):

MS provided Jira and Confluence had bugs which is fixed(As of 06/08/2021) you can try and test.

Comment: Can you point to a specific bug being fixed, and how it relates to the error in the question? If not, this would be better as a comment.